# How can I convert a combination function to permutation function?

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I'm working on a separate program which has a bunch of `gui`, so I made a simpler program in an attempt to ask for help.

I don't really know `permutations` and `combinations` that well.

Anyway, I have a piece of code here which solves this function:

```
F (n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!)
```

You can change the n and r in the code and it'll give you the answer for those two inputs.

```
public class peanuts
{

static int n,r;


public static void main (String[] args)
{

   n= 8;
    r=3;

  int m=1;

    if(n>>1 < r)
        r = n - r;
    for(int o=n+1-r;o<n+1;o++)
        m *= o;
    for(int o=r;o>0;o--)
        m /= o;
    Math.round(m);

      System.out.println ("C("+n+","+r+ ") is "+ m );
}}
```

I want to modify it slightly so it solves this permutation function:

```
F (n,r) = n!/(n-r)!)
```

Comment: Question for future question writing, why did you put all that non-code into code format?

Comment: I guess he did it for readability though you can use `blockquote` for such purpose

Comment: Just put it into my GUI. Works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second for loop that divides by `r!`.

```
for(int o=r;o>0;o--)
  m /= o;
```

This divides `m` by `r!`. Remove this loop.

Comment: Remove this? `for(int o=r;o>0;o--)
        m /= o;`

Answer (score 2):

Formula for calculating the **permutation** is:

```
F (n,r) = n!/(n-r)!
```

Formula for calculating the **combination** is:

```
F (n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!)
```

So you just need to remove the second `for` loop in which you are dividing by factorial r ie, remove this:

```
for(int o=r;o>0;o--)
  m /= o;
```